# When to use sgesvd over sgesdd in LAPACK?

Tags: lapack, lapacke

I'm using **sgesvd** with a very large matrix (5000x3000)...and it's super slow.
I have heard that **sgesdd** is much faster, so why should I consider to use **sgesvd** over **sgesdd**?

**sgesdd** Is using divide and counquer algorithm.

**sgesvd** Is using QR-factorization